# Read data from Microsoft SQL database on Remote Desktop via. R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, odbc, rodbc

My data is loaded on Micorsoft SQL server on a Remote Desktop with Microsoft Windows Server 2012. I want to access Data via R. I know its possible via [RODBC](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dbinterface.html) with

```
odbcConnect(dsn, uid="", pwd="")
```

But I am confused on what to enter  on dsn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it depends on whether you want to use ODBC DSN or DSN-less connection string, the type of authentication and the driver.

Here's an example of DSN-less connection string, using domain authentication and SQL Server driver:

```
odbcDriverConnect(connection="server=MYDB.mynet.tld;database=mydb_prod;trusted_connection=true;Port=1433;driver={SQL Server};TDS_Version=7.0;")
```

Here's another example, with SQL authentication and FreeTDS driver (e.g. on Mac or Linux)

```
odbcDriverConnect(connection="server=MYDB.mynet.tld;database=mydb_prod;uid=myuser;pwd=mypass;Port=1433;driver=FreeTDS;TDS_Version=7.0;")
```

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for more examples of what can go in the "connection" element.

Here's a function I use to open connection in a cross-platform way:

```
require(RODBC)

connect <- function(host, db, user=NULL, pass=NULL, platform="win" ){

  # TODO: Check input paramaters and add a branch for SQL auth on windows

  if(platform == "win")
  {
    c <- odbcDriverConnect(connection=paste0("server=",host,
                                             ";database=",db,
                                             ";trusted_connection=true;Port=1433;driver={SQL Server};TDS_Version=7.0;"))

    if(class(c) == 'RODBC') 
    {  
      writeLines("Successfilly opened connection to db")
      return(c)
    } 
    else
    {
      writeLines(paste0("Error opening connection: ", as.character(c)))
    }
  }  

  if(platform == "mac")
  {
    c <- odbcDriverConnect(connection=paste0("server=",host,
                                             ";database=",db,
                                             ";uid=",user,
                                             ";pwd=",pass,
                                             ";Port=1433;driver=FreeTDS;TDS_Version=7.0;"))

    if(class(c) == 'RODBC') 
    {  
      writeLines("Successfilly opened connection to db")
      return(c)
    } 
    else
    {
      writeLines(paste0("Error opening connection: ", as.character(c)))
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: I got an error when I entered the following as the connection name `odbcDriverConnect(connection="server=10.100.0.1;database=db_name;uid=id;pwd=pwd;Port=1433;driver=FreeTDS;TDS_Version=7.0;")` 

Error

`Warning messages:  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message 
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
2:.....
  ODBC connection failed`

Comment: @FistOfFury Sorry I am no longer working on this and forgot how this was solved.